# List comprehension for ternary operator python3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, ternary-operator

I have a list of string called `givenProductions`. Each string has a uppercase and '-' and may contain a lowercase.

Example: givenProductions can be `['S-AA', 'A-a', 'A-b']`

Now I want to fill two sets:

1. terminals (contain only lowercase from `givenProductions`) and
2. nonTerminals (contain only uppercase from `givenProductions`)

in just one line

I tried this ...

```
terminals.append(ch) if (ch >= 'a' and ch <= 'z') else nonTerminals.append(ch) if (ch != '-') else print() for ch in prod for prod in givenProductions
```

which resulted in a syntax error

```
File "<stdin>", line 2
    terminals.append(ch) if (ch >= 'a' and ch <= 'z') else nonTerminals.append(ch) if (ch != '-')   else print ('-') for ch in prod  for prod in givenProductions
                                                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What's the correct way of writing it?

Comment: Productions, Terminals and Symbols...I smell Context-Free Languages/Grammars...

Comment: Yes I am writting a program for lr(0) parser ... this is just a part of that code

Comment: Has noting to do with CFGs, just trying to shorten the length of code.

Comment: post the output that you want

Comment: Minor side-note: This is a classic case for Python's support for chained comparisons; testing `'a' <= ch <= 'z'` would be equivalent to `ch >= 'a' and ch <= 'z'`, but more straightforwardly readable as testing whether `ch` occurs in a given range (and trivially more efficient, given it only loads `ch` once).

Comment: Thanks a lot @ShadowRanger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no use to list comprehensions if you do not care about the result. Just write it as a regular `for` loop:

```
for prod in givenProductions:
    for ch in prod:
        if ch >= 'a' and ch <= 'z':
            terminals.append(ch)
        elif ch != '-':
            nonTerminals.append(ch)
```

Note that the order of the two `for` loops is changed! If you **really** want to use a list comprehension, you must do the same. There is no need for print, just finish the ternary with `None` (which `print()` produces anyway). Also, square brackets (`[]`) are required for a list comprehension:

```
>>> givenProductions = ['S-AA', 'A-a', 'A-b']
>>> terminals, nonTerminals = [], []
>>> [terminals.append(ch) if (ch >= 'a' and ch <= 'z') else nonTerminals.append(ch) if (ch != '-') else None for prod in givenProductions for ch in prod]
>>> terminals, nonTerminals
>>> print(terminals, nonTerminals)
['a', 'b'] ['S', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
```

Note that this creates and throws away a list of `None` elements. Using a set comprehension (`{}`) is more memory efficient, but less CPU efficient.

```
>>> waste = {terminals.append(ch) if (ch >= 'a' and ch <= 'z') else nonTerminals.append(ch) if (ch != '-') else None for prod in givenProductions for ch in prod}
>>> print(waste)
{None}
```

Comment: As a rule, using comprehensions of any kind for side-effects is frowned upon; they're a functional programming construct, and functional programming constructs are supposed to be side-effect free (Python doesn't enforce this, but any time you use them for side-effects, you risk confusing maintainers, and, as in this case, pointlessly creating potentially large, pointless temporaries, or doing the extra work of a `set` comprehension for no real reason).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Agreed, I do not see any point in using a comprehension here. It is possible, but not advisable.